# JavaScript li element background color not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

As you can see, I have declared the variables in a global scope so I can access them in different functions, and now I am trying to change the background color of an `<li>` element in  an if statement. But I'm getting an error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')". I have tried two ways but neither of them worked and its taking so much of my time.

Below is my JS code:

```
var vals;
var rows;
var sum;
var rowsarr = [];
var avg;
var lines;

function obser1() {
    const trades = document.querySelector('.scrollbar-dark');
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
                vals = [...mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelectorAll("span")].map(span => span.textContent);
                lines = [...mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelectorAll("li")];
                if (vals.length == 4) {


                  //value of rows variable 
                        rows = vals[2];
                        rowsarr.push(rows);
                    }
                    if (vals.length == 3) {
                        rows = vals[1];
                        rowsarr.push(rows);
                    }
                    console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
                    console.log(rows+"  rows");
                }
            })
            function arraysum(x, y) {
                return parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y);
            }
            sum = rowsarr.reduce(arraysum);
            console.log(rowsarr.length + "  length");
            if (rowsarr.length >= 100 && rowsarr.length<115) {
                avg = sum / 50;
                console.log("average is  " + avg);
            }
            /*This is the problem*/
            if (rows > avg) {
                console.log(rows + "  large" + "  average  " + avg);

            //--1
            //lines.style.backgroundColor = "white";

            //--2
            //for (let i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            //    lines[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";

            //}
            
            
        }
    });
    observer.observe(trades, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        attributes: true,
        characterData: true
    })
   
}

window.setTimeout(btn4, 1000);
window.setTimeout(obser1, 1900);
```

Comment: The example doesn't seem to ever give `lines` a value? Which means it'd be undefined

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry. i edited the question... I had already tried this but its not working..

Comment: Does `lines.length` output anything?

Comment: Can you share your HTML or/and a `console.log()` of `lines`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `lines.length` outputs 0

Comment: @Gass a `console.log(lines)` outputs nothing. not zero, just nothing...

Comment: Well, there is the problem. You are trying to make changes to an HTML tag that doesn't exist.

Comment: Add a condition to fix this problem `if (rows > avg && lines !== null)`

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: i made a new variable called `linesin` and then i pushed `mutation.addedNode[0]` into it. then i tried `linesin.style.backgroundColor = "white"`. its not giving me an error but the color is not showing on the website. Now im going to assign a class to the linesin element and add  a style in css. @Gass

Comment: Before trying to make changes to the HTML element, make sure JS is properly selecting the element. It appears you are struggling wit that. Put extra attention to the query Selectors